# Is there a method of integrating React and Django without implementing a Django RESTful API?

Tags: reactjs, django

When using [vanilla JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software), you can just deliver HTML files to Django and just code between the lines in the Python language in order to create the functionalities that you need in your backend side of your web application.

However, this is not the case when we use React. Is there a similar way (as vanilla JavaScript and HTML files) for integrating React and Django (except for using [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API endpoints)?

Answer (score 0):

Using React and Django are two different technologies, and you need APIs to interact, whereas this is not the case writing vanilla JavaScript in Django HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

It's called React [server-side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering). If you add Django to this and search for it, you'll get a couple of hits, like this tutorial below:

*[Setting Up Server Side Rendering with React, Redux, and Django](https://medium.com/meural-product-development/setting-up-server-side-rendering-with-react-redux-and-django-4d6f4d2fd705)*

It looks doable as long as you are somewhat proficient in [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) as well.